# Tooltip for view based NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, tooltip, nstableview

I have a tooltip:

```
cellView.textField.toolTip = cellView.textField.stringValue;
```

It shows always, but I need to show tooltip only if text clipped... How I can achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Set `allowsExpansionToolTips` property to YES for Table View Cell in xib.

[image]

Comment: `allowsExpansionToolTips` of the text field, not `allowsExpansionToolTips` of the table view.

Comment: @Willeke its available for the view-based table view. From [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428962-allowsexpansiontooltips?language=objc) : In general, it is recommended to turn this on for NSTextField instances in a view-based NSTableView.

Comment: @Willeke NSTableView is subclass of NSControl, allowsExpansionToolTips is method of NSControl. tableView.allowsExpansionToolTips = true  code is working fine on mac app.

Comment: `tableView.allowsExpansionToolTips = YES` turns on expansion tooltips for the cells in a cell based table view. Does `tableView.allowsExpansionToolTips = YES` turn on `allowsExpansionToolTips` of all controls in the cells of a view based table view?

Comment: OP is asking to display tooltip if text is clipped in table view text field and tableView.allowsExpansionToolTips = YES will display a tooltip. Is it not working for you ?

Comment: No, it isn't working and the recommendation is to turn `allowsExpansionToolTips` on for the text fields instead of the table view. Is it working for you without turning on `allowsExpansionToolTips` for the text fields?

Comment: @Willeke You are right. Setting allowsExpansionToolTips value for Table View Cell is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by implementing the text field delegate method, controlTextDidEndEditing, and checking the size of the text.  I found that the size returned by sizeWithAttributes: didn't match the size I would have expected when I filled the text field, so I just determined the value I needed for my if statement empirically (in this example I had the text field's value bound to a property, theText).

```
-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj {
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromRect([obj.object frame]));
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:13] forKey:@"NSFontAttributeName"];
    NSSize size = [theText sizeWithAttributes:dict];
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSize(size));
    if (size.width >69) {
        [obj.object setToolTip:theText];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: allowsExpansionToolTips (in [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428962-allowsexpansiontooltips), [Obj-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428962-allowsexpansiontooltips?language=objc))

> Expansion tooltips are shown when the cell cannot show the full
> content and the user hovers the pointer over the control.